# Поменять контент карусели при переключении между табами

Tags: javascript, slick.js

Есть переключатель между табами (3 шт) и в каждой должна быть карусель (slick) с разным контентом. Делал при помощи js, просто добавлял всем класс hidden (display:none), а у нужного удалял этот класс. Работает, но слайды первое время сплюснтые какие-то и только после смены одного слайда ширина возвращается.
Вот так выглядит до смены
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Думал сделать при помощи innerHTML, заменить внутренности дива-обёртки на другие, но что-то не задалось. Может я что-то не так сделал или есть более надёжный способ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На английском стаке дали ответ: надо уничтожить карусель, а потом инициализировать снова.

```
$('.my-carousel').slick('destroy');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9r63vkqa/